# Login authentication using NodeJS: ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token

Tags: node.js, authentication, request, csrf

I am trying to use NodeJS to login a server with a username and password.  I am having trouble managing the csrf token that is returned from the GET request.
My login script is like this:

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');
var cookieJar = request.jar();
request = request.defaults({jar: cookieJar});
var baseURL = 'http://192.168.2.110:3000';

request(
  {
  url:  baseURL+'/login',
  method: 'GET',
  jar: cookieJar,
  followAllRedirects: true
  },
  function (error, httpResponse, body) {
    if(error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }

  console.log(cookieJar);

  request(
  {
    method: 'POST',
    url: baseURL+'/login',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    form: {username:'user', password:'pass'},
    jar: cookieJar,
    followAllRedirects: true
  },
  function(error, httpResponse, body) {
    if(error) {
       console.error(error);
       return;
    }
  });
});
```

`cookieJar` seems to be populated properly with after the `GET` request. The console output is the following:

```
RequestJar {
  _jar:
   CookieJar {
     enableLooseMode: true,
     store:
      { idx: { '192.168.2.110':
         { '/':
            { _csrf: Cookie="_csrf=s%3AIV027NBEoYzaiGkKTtBkhYl8.5HHLT%2Fgk2H%2BUhv1gKHTWKVNUoE%2FD86ZBWQK5CI%2BHL7s; Path=/; hostOnly=true; aAge=291ms; cAge=291ms",
              _csrfToken: Cookie="_csrfToken=rvxBsdwl-Y9dW0WsFKDEI5uZ-GaQ7KtzDuiU; Path=/; hostOnly=true; aAge=292ms; cAge=292ms",
              'connect.sid': Cookie="connect.sid=s%3AgM1UcRjVXjj4LJUM5AzIeaC_ehgSD-ff.7Qjn9vjAp%2FZAhTB5S64mwces7usO%2FN%2BM1YnWOlvB9I4; Path=/; HttpOnly; hostOnly=true; aAge=295ms; cAge=295ms" } } } } } }
```

However, I get the

> ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token.

The server is running the user management boilerplate drywall.

I am not sure what I am missing?  Why would I get an invalid token if I am passing it right back in the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I have not had the chance to look into this before now.
I ended up using a function that would look for the `_csrfToken`cookie. then I used it to populate `x-csrf-token` in the ajax call:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
};
```

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: message,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  headers: {'x-csrf-token': csrfToken},
  success: function(data) {
    ....
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    ....
  }
 });
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)